# Eager loading relational data without including link table data using KnexJS or TypeORM

Tags: postgresql, orm

I have **Table A** and **Table B** in my Postgres DB. The relations are built using link tables.

**Example**: ***ab_link*** table record contains ***a_id*** and ***b_id***.

What I am trying to do is get the ObjectA from table A with related ObjectB nested inside ObjectA.

When I am querying the data the ab_link table data is also added.

I have seen examples where we manually process the data after querying and I am trying to avoid that because my data relations are complex and nested multi-levels.

How can we get the A and B data without the ab_link recorded added to the queried data using **KnexJS**/**TypeORM**?

```
// USING KNEXJS
      const a = await this.db('a')
      .innerJoin('ab_links', 'a.id', 'ab_links.a_id')
      .innerJoin('b', 'ab_links.b_id', 'b.id')
      .where('a.id', id)
      .then((rows) => {
        return rows
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
      Output a: {
                  id: 2,
                  name: 'Test',
                  b_id: 2
                }

// USING TYPEORM
      const req = await (await this.aRepository.queryBuilder(`a`))
        .leftJoinAndSelect('a.ab_links', 'abl')
        .leftJoinAndSelect('abl.b', 'b')
        .where({ id: id })
        .getOne();
Output:       {
        id:1,
        name: 'test',
        ab_links: {
          id:4,
          a_id:1,
          b_id:2,
          b: {
            id:2,
            name: 'test2'
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Please post your query so far.

Comment: @RohitGupta updated.

Comment: I see no SQL. That looks more like a question for Stackoverflow.